# Value error in Python while working with tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, conv-neural-network

I'm getting this error when trying to run a script:

```
Input 0 of layer "conv2d_1" is incompatible with the layer: expected min_ndim=4, 
found ndim=2. Full shape received: (None, 6).
```

I have an input data of shape (332240, 6, 160,160). Basically for each target data, I wanna input 6 images. I also have a secondary dataset of shape (332240, 6) that I concatenate with the image data after I flatten the images.
Here's the code I used to build the model.

```
    image_inputs = [Input(shape=(160,160,1) for _ in range(6)]
    array_input = Input(shape=(6,)

    # Convolutional Layer
    conv_outputs = []
    for imgs in image_inputs:
      
      x = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform')(imgs)
      x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(x)
  
      # Flatten the convolutional output
      x = Flatten()(x)
      conv_outputs.append(x)
    
    #concatenate the flattened images together 
    conv_concat = Concatenate()(conv_outputs)
    
    # Concatenate the flattened images and array inputs
    concatenated_inputs = Concatenate()([conv_concat, array_input])

    # Create the model architecture
    for units in (100,10):
        concatenated_inputs = Dense(units, activation='relu')(concatenated_inputs)

    # Output layer for regression
    output_layer = Dense(1, activation='linear')(concatenated_inputs)

    # Create the final model with inputs and output
    final_model = Model(inputs=[image_inputs, array_input], outputs=output_layer)

    # Compile the model
    if optimizer == 'sgd':
        sgd_optimizer = SGD(learning_rate = 0.01, momentum = 0.9)
        optimizer = sgd_optimizer

    final_model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss= 'mean_squared_error', metrics= ['mean_squared_error','mean_absolute_error'])

final_model.fit([img_array,int_array],target_array,validation_split = 0.2, verbose = 1, batch_size = 32)
```

img_array has a shape of (332240, 6, 160, 160) while value_array has a shape of (332240,6) and target_array has a shape of (3332240,1).

Answer (score 1):

If you have 7 `Input` layers, you need 7 inputs. The problem is that the network doesn't split the `(332240, 6, 160, 160)` of your `img_array` to the 6 `Input` layers, but handles it as one input and gives it all to the first `Input`, and then the second `Input` gets the `int_array` and the shape missmatch error occures.
The following get you 6 images with one channel and one array input, and the target data for 1000 points:

```
inputs = [np.random.rand(1000, 160, 160, 1).astype(np.float32) for _ in range(6)] + [np.random.rand(1000, 6).astype('float32')]
target_array = np.random.rand(1000, 1)
```

Note that this is not useful data but should only show the right input shape.